# MySQL: Smallest datatype for one bit

Tags: sql, mysql, database, types, sqldatatypes

I would like to add a column to the table which contains either of two values: 1 or 0.

What would be the smallest datatype to store the data in MySQL?

A `TINYINT(1)` can contain numbers between `-127` to `127`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use bit(1)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

BOOL is stored in MySQL as TINYINT which would take 1 full byte

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html

A bit(1) would normally also take 1-byte but if there are multiple bits in a single record, then they get stored in the same byte, up to 8 per byte.

Comment: A single BIT column will also take one full Byte. However, if you have 8 BITs next to each other, they will take one byte.

Comment: @Mchl - I was just typing that out

Comment: @Mchl - Are you saying that (to pack the bits into a byte appropriately) that the 8 columns have to be declared together, with no other columns between them?

Comment: @Damien - no, they just have to be on the same table.

Comment: what confused me was the phrase (in Mchls comment) "next to each other"

Answer (score 0):

Its an ideal case for a boolean data type