# What datatype should I use for values between 0 to 3

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

My field in the database will contain only 3 possible values: 0, 1 and 2. So, I'm wondering what datatype should I use? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968495/mysql-smallest-datatype-for-one-bit) and it seems that I should use tinyint(1), but that has range from -127 to 126, so am wondering is that my choice or is there actually something better?

Comment: Tinyint looks right for what you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tinyint(1) unsigned` is probably the right fit for this

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended but... I was initially thinking if space is really that big of an issue this may have been worth exploring.

If you can live with NULL, 0, 1 instead of 0,1,2, then boolean/bit may work as well.

However, looks like boolean and tinyint are practically the same.  And tinyint has the smallest footprint of all datatypes in mysql. See [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

Comment: yes, according to the link it looks like they both take only 1 byte

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make sure that the number entered is only 0, 1, or 2 then it would be best to add a CHECK constraint to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE
    tableName
ADD CONSTRAINT 
    checkConstain
CHECK (columnName BETWEEN 0 and 2)
```

You can see an example of this working on [SQL Fiddel](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/719cc)