# Best performance in MYSQL 8 between BIT or BOOL for search

Tags: mysql, database-performance, mysql-8.0

I'm using MySQL 8.0 CE. I have an attribute where I want to store a TRUE or FALSE status and I want it to use as little space as possible.

After reading the answers in this question:
[MySQL: Smallest datatype for one bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968495/mysql-smallest-datatype-for-one-bit) and the MySQL documentation [Bit-Value Type - BIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html) and [Integer Types (Exact Value)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), I understand that at storage level it is better is to use BIT(1) because BOOL is actually a TINYINT(1) and therefore uses full 1byte.

At storage level it is clear that BIT(1) is the best option but, at performance level when searching for true or false?

If I understand correctly BIT would store 1 or 0 while BOOL stores TRUE or FALSE.

That difference makes that when searching between both possibilities one of the types is better optimized for it?

Thanks.

Comment: This smells of Premature Optimization

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @SideTest - Devlin ir referring to a common practice of programmers of spending time up front optimizing things that won't matter enough to warrant the time spent.

Comment: @devlincarnate - Ah ok! Yes! it's possible. But I like to get to the bottom of things, even if I don't use it later :) Besides, it's really a hobby, so time is relative. In real life with deadlines I wouldn't have been able to do so much, although it's also true that I like to optimize things as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BIT(1)` also requires minimum 1 byte, so you're not saving any space compared to `BOOL`/`TINYINT`. Both take 1 byte.

Speaking to MySQL developers, they usually wince when I bring up the `BIT` data type. It's full of known bugs, and likely undiscovered bugs. The internal code is poorly understood. They told me to just use `TINYINT`.

By the way, MySQL doesn't have a true `BOOL` type. `BOOL` is just an alias for `TINYINT(1)`, and there is no true or false value. The "false" value is literally the integer 0, and the "true" value is the integer 1. In other words, you can `SUM()` a column that is supposedly boolean, and you get an integer sum equal to the number of rows where the column is "true." This is not compliant with standard SQL (it makes no sense to SUM() a boolean column), but it's the way `BOOL` is implemented in MySQL.

Comment: In the other direction, `NULL` acts a lot like false, and any non-zero value is "true"

Comment: @RickJames I wouldn't say `NULL` is like false, because `NOT NULL` is not true.

Comment: What logic is there in the existence of `BIT(1)`, `BOOL`/`TINYINT(1)` if they all take up 1Byte? Anyway, seeing that they all occupy the same space and that, as @RickJames says, there is no noticeable performance improvement, I'll listen to you and use `TINYINT(1)`.

Comment: @SideTest, MySQL implements the `BIT` string data type because part of the SQL standard, so clients will expect it to be supported. If you store longer bit strings, they use bytes efficiently. But they allocate a whole byte at a time. So a string of `N` bits uses `(N+7)/8` bytes.

Comment: Do you mean that in the SQL standard `BIT(1)` will occupy only 1bit and not the Byte? Another thing is that later it will be grouped in bytes.

Comment: No, the standard only specified that `BIT` is a data type that has semantics of allowing the caller to address individual bits. It doesn't dictate how it should be stored. I'm talking about how MySQL implements it.

Comment: "NULL acts a lot like false" yet is not false at all, NULL is nothing. "Nothing" means just that and so isn't definitively true or false (yes or no). So if you rely on NULL, does it mean "nothing has been set yet" OR "false/no"? This is a bad approach. "0" is false/no, everything else is true/yes (usually preferring "1") and these are actual values that can be determined to mean something. So then you have "0" false, "1" true, "NULL" option is not set

Comment: @James: NULL is not true, therefore if the expression in a WHERE clause evaluates to NULL, then the result set will not include that row. That's the only way the NULL "acts like" false.

Comment: Null is not true the same as many things, a non empty array, an object, a non empty string, but you wouldn't use any of these to signify "true/yes" either. NULL may well be "false" in terms of how a language interprets it like PHP, but as a raw data type it is accurately "NULL" to mean "nothing". And "nothing" is not anything, including "false", it's specifically "nothing"

Comment: @James: As a practical effect, specifically _in MySQL's implementation,_ if you query `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name;`, the result will include rows where `name` evaluates to a numeric value other than zero. The result will not include rows where `name` is NULL. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: IMO that SQL is ambiguous then. You should have queries that specify explicitly what you want. NOT NULL etc.

Comment: @BillKarwin Were those MySQL developers you spoke with speaking in relation to MySQL 5 or 8?

Comment: To be clear: **MySQL does not implement BOOL** it's merely an alias for tinyint ***for creation only*** (table schema is set with tinyint and that's what you will see in the structure) - documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html (both 5.7 and 8.0); you can test this with `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`

Answer (score 0):

Consideing that in mysql boolean is the same as tinyint(1). That said, boolean always uses 1 byte per column but bit(n) will use as few bytes that are needed to hold the given number of bits. BIT save some space however i would use boolean because it makes things simpler at the moment you want to query a database. in terms you can have values other than 0 or 1 if you are not careful. To avoid this, you can use the aliases TRUE and FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

(In addition to what Bill says...)

I have a Rule Of Thumb:  "If a back-of-envelope estimate doesn't suggest at least a 10% improvement, move on to some other optimization".  Couple that with the fact that even if a single-bit bool would shrink the row length by 7 bits, that would probably be less than 1% savings.  So, I move on.

OTOH, If you have lots of booleans, then consider the `SET` datatype, which can handle up to 64 'booleans' in 8 bytes or less.  But it's rather clumsy.  So is a similar thing with the 64 bits of `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, together with shifting and boolean operators (`<<`, `&`, etc.)

If you need to `INDEX` one or several booleans, forget it.  About the only case where indexing works is in a composite (multi-column) index where one of the columns is [effectively] `TINYINT NOT NULL`

Comment: Yes, I had looked at the `set` type as well and will consider it in the future, but for this case I simply need two options.

Comment: @SideTest - Sounds like my RoT rules.